# How to click on a p:commandButton using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, callback, commandbutton

There are many  tag in my JSF page.I want to click a `p:commandButton` using javascript in one of the forms. But it doesn't work. When  I debug it use chrome ,it prompt The `p:commandButton` can't be found , that is say $("#templetFile\:editButton") is null, why?

There is my code:

```html
<h:form id="templetFile" style="height:100%">
<input type="button" value = "click me" onclick="testOnclick();"/>
<p:commandButton id="editButton" value="ceshi" styleClass="button"
 action="#{advancedQueryManager.editModAndClass()}" onclick="getValddd()"
 style="display:none">
 <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update="templFile"
 listener="#{advancedQueryManager.onreturn()}" />
</p:commandButton>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
   function testOnclick() {
    var a =$("#templetFile\\:editButton");
    a.click();
   }
   function getValddd(){
    alert("Allready onclick!");
   }
  </script>
  </h:form>
```

And if I using this js code 
var b = document.getElementById('editButton');
I still can't get the p:commandButton element.Why?And how to get the p:commandButton using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, jsf creates a new id for the button so `document.getElementById('editButton')` does not work. In order to solve this you may add an arbitrary style class to button like;

`styleClass="button myButtonToClick"` and javascript should be like this;

```
var x =document.getElementsByClassName("myButtonToClick");
x[0].click();
```

Comment: Nice. Pretty simple solution.